# Bean creation exception

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

My application context looks likt this,

```
<bean id="caseTxBo" class="gov.case.rcp.bo.impl.caseTxBoImpl" >
            <property name="caseTxDao" ref="caseTxDao" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="caseTxDao" class="gov.case.rcp.dao.impl.caseTxDaoImpl" >
            <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
```

Action class gets the context like this:

```
ServletContext context = request.getSession().getServletContext();
     BeanFactory factory = WebApplicationContextUtils.
           getRequiredWebApplicationContext(context);
     CaseTxBOImpl caseTxBo = (

             caseTxBoImpl) factory.getBean("caseTxBo");

     List<caseTxPmt> errorVarList =       
     caseTxBo.getcaseTxDao().findAllcaseTx();

    model.put("caseTxList", caseTxList);
```

BOImpl implements Dao and DAOImpl implements Dao:

DaoImpl has the implementation and returns caseTxList.

but I get a runTimeException as

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'caseTxBo' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/classes/applicationContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'caseTxDao' while setting bean property 'caseTxDao'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'caseTxDao' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/classes/applicationContext.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'sessionFactory' of bean class [gov.case.rcp.pp.dao.impl.CaseTxDaoImpl]: Bean property 'sessionFactory' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
follows:
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:275)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:104)
```

Where did i go wrong?

Comment: Did you read the entire exception message (the root cause is at its very end)? What part of the message did you not understand?

Comment: Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
they both match.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Bean property `'sessionFactory'` is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
>   follows:
>   at `org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference`(`BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:275`)

The error message is pretty clear. Open your `CaseTxDaoImpl` and make sure there is a following method there:

```
public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
}
```

BTW this:

```
ServletContext context = request.getSession().getServletContext();
BeanFactory factory = WebApplicationContextUtils.
       getRequiredWebApplicationContext(context);
factory.getBean("caseTxBo")
```

is pretty low-level usage of Spring and an anti-pattern. Are you using any web framework? Typically they integrate with Spring quite well.

Comment: is it the hibernatesession factory? my DAOImpl extends JdbcDaoSupport. Im new to spring integration. my app follows struts framework and spring integration for injection of beans. it uses both JdbcDaoSupport and HibernateDaoSupport..but this DaoImpl uses JdbcDaoSupport.